# What is ActiveRecord Persistence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have looked at the documentation, a bunch of SO threads, but I can't see clearly defined anywhere what persistence is, and where it should be used.

I see it is something to do with checking if a record is new or not, but I don't see why that is useful.

By 'clearly', I mean 'simply enough for a newbie to understand' :)

Comment: Did you mean `persisted?` method of Active Record?

Comment: Yes - in general, I want to understand Persistence, and why I should use it (or not).

Comment: persisted? only used to check an object save in DB or not I mean it is in new state or in edit mode

Comment: Are you referring to the `ActiveRecord::Persistence` module? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `persisted?` method return true if the object has been persisted. Persisted means the object has been saved in the database. You can only call it on ActiveRecord objects.

```
user = User.new
user.persisted?
=> false
user. name = 'test'
user.save
user.persisted?
=> true
```

Comment: Why not use the boolean from user.save! ?

Comment: The save result is meant to check if the save is successful.
The persisted? result is meant to know if the object lives in database.

Comment: when else would you use it than after a save, to see if the save succeeded or not?

Comment: If you have a bunch of objects in an array, with dynamically created ones and others retrieved from database. Then you would want to loop over the array to save only the non persisted ones.

Comment: so basically it checks whether you still need to save something or not, that is the main use case?

Comment: What about ActiveRecord::Persistence - what Persistence - mean ?